# Finding files with bash and copy to another location and reducing depth of folders

Tags: bash, copy, find, directory

I'm trying to recover a mates hard drive, there is no structure what so ever so music and images are everywhere but in named folders sometimes >5 folders deep, I've managed to write a one-liner that finds the files and copies them to a mounted drive but it preserves the file structure completely. What I'm after is a bit of code that searches the drive and copies to another location and copies just the parent folder with the mp3/jpg files within and not the complete path. The other issue I have is the music is /folder/folder/folder/Artist/1.mp3..2.mp3..10.mp3 etc etc so I have to preserve the folder 'Artist' to give him any hope of finding his tracks again.

What I have working currently:

```
find /media/HP/ -name *.mp3 -fprintf /media/HP/MUSIC/Script.sh 'mkdir -p "/media/HP/MUSIC/%h" \n cp "%h/%f" "/media/HP/MUSIC/%h/"\n'
```

I then run the script.sh and it does all the copying.

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you've already written a one-liner that preserves the file structure, but then you seem to be asking for some code that preserves the file structure. Please clarify.

Comment: OK sorry I'll try and re-phrase:

I have many music and image files scattered over a HD I'm trying to salvage for a mate, currently the files are buried very deep as much as 10 folders in some cases, the one-liner I've managed to create works but preserves the full folder structure so copies them 10 folders deep in the new location. What I'm trying to achieve is the found file copied with just the parent directory only for example:

/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/artist name/1.mp3 -> /artist name/1.mp3 

Thank you for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do will be along the lines of:

```
mkdir "$dest/$(basename $(dirname $source))"
```

Answer (score 1):

OK folks - thanks for the input it did make me think deeper about this and I've come up with a result with the help of a colleague (thanks SiG):

This one-liner finds the files, and writes a script file to run separately but does copy across just the last folder as I wanted initially.

The Code:

```
find /some/folder/ -name *.mp3 |  awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}{print "mkdir -p \"/some/new/place/" $(NF-1) "\"\ncp -v -p \"" $0 "\" \"/some/new/place/" $(NF-1) "/" $NF "\""}' > script.sh
```

The output is:

```
mkdir -p "/media/HP/MUSIC/Satize"  cp -v -p "/media/HP/Users/REBEKAH/Music/Satize/You Don't Love Me.mp3" "/media/HP/MUSIC/Satize/You Don't Love Me.mp3"
```

When script.sh is run it does all the work and I end up with a very reduced file structure I can copy to a new drive.

Thanks again folks much appreciated.
KjF

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the operation recursively ( entering directory by directory ), what you can do is everytime save your path as: `Road_Dir=$(pwd)`(let's say dir1/dir2/dir3/)

Then you detect your artist_name directory you save it is `Music_Dir=$(pwd)`
Finally you could extract your artist_name directory with the simple command:

`Final_Dir=${Music_Dir##$Road_Dir/}`  (wich means take out the string $Road_Dir/ from $Music_Dir beginning from the left of $Music_Dir)

With this Final_Dir will contain `artist_name`, and you can copy your music file as $Final_Dir/Music.mp3 ...